# Generating totally ordered free commutative monoids

Tags: reference-request, order-theory, semigroups-and-monoids, ordered-groups

Let’s say I have a set $A$. I build the free commutative monoid $M$ generated by $A$.

1. When can a well-order on $A$ be extended to $M$, in a way that is compatible with its monoid structure? I am interested both in the case when $A$ is finite and infinite.
2. Under which conditions would such an extension be unique?

Comment: Be extended to what on $M$? another well-order? What have you tried so far? when $|A|=2$?

Comment: You could use the lexicographic order, that's total again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your first question, the answer is positive with lexicographic ordering (as said by Chris).
Your monoid is $\mathbb{N}^{(A)}$ (i.e. the set of mappings $\alpha: A\to \mathbb{N}$ with finite support, additive version) or $M=\{A^{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in \mathbb{N}^{(A)}}$ for a multiplicative version using the [multiindex notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-index_notation) like in the multivariate polynomials (take e.g. the ring $\mathbb{Z}[A]$).

An easy way to see that this is an ordering is to consider the free commutative group over the same alphabet $A$, i.e. $\mathbb{Z}^{(A)}$ and ($A$ being still supposed totally ordered by
$<$) the set
$$
P:=\{\alpha\in \mathbb{Z}^{(A)}\setminus\{0\}\ |\ \alpha(\min(supp(\alpha)))>0\}
$$
where the support of $\alpha$ is
$$
supp(\alpha)=\{a\in A\ |\ \alpha(a)\not=0\}
$$
in other words $P$ is just the set of non-zero multiindices such that the coefficient at the least place is $>0$ (for this, only total order is required). One has just to check that

1. $P+P\subset P$

   $P\cap -P=\emptyset$

   for $\alpha,\beta\in \mathbb{N}^{(A)}$, $\alpha\prec_{lex}\beta$ iff 
   $\beta-\alpha\in P$

   $\prec_{lex}$ extends the given ordering on $A$

   if $(A,<)$ is well ordered, so is $(\mathbb{N}^{(A)},\prec_{lex})$

which is maybe long but straightforward.

For your second question, one can see that this extension is unique iff $|A|\leq 1$ ($A$ is empty or a singleton) as, if $|A|\geq 2$ all lexicographic orderings are different
(and exchanged by permutations in case $A$ is finite). Still if $|A|\geq 2$ (and totally ordered), there are orders which are not in this class as the "graded lexicographic ordering
$\prec_{grlex}$" obtained by
$$
\alpha\prec_{grlex}\beta \Longleftrightarrow |\alpha|<|\beta|\mbox{ or }(|\alpha|=|\beta| 
\mbox{ and } \alpha\prec_{lex}\beta)
$$
... and in all cases (when $A$ is not empty), the reverse ordering is different from the given one.

Hope it helps, do not hesitate if something is unclear.